# R Script permissions error

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I executed this to check to see if I have write permissions on a folder and it fails (returns -1). I am a system admin and SQL admin.  I have full access to this directory but the R Script says I do not.  If I change the mode of the script to check for read or execute permissions, it succeeds (returns 0).  What else can I check to fix this?

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
       @language = N'R'
      ,@script = N'OutputDataSet <- data.frame(file.access("C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER/R_SERVICES/library/", 2));'
WITH RESULT SETS (([DefaultLibraryName] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL));
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you 'might' need to grant the proper authority on that folder to the Windows group **SQLRUserGroup**.

I have a test SQL Server instance where R-Services is installed.  I took your script and changed the directory to be *C:/Scripts* (just as a test).

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
       @language = N'R'
      ,@script = N'OutputDataSet <- data.frame(file.access("C:/scripts/", 2));'
WITH RESULT SETS (([DefaultLibraryName] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL));
GO
```

I got the same -1 return code as you.

I then granted FULL access against C:/Scripts to the Windows group **SQLRUserGroup** and ran the same script code.  It executed successfully with a zero (0) being returned.

Comment: How did you grant permissions to the GROUP?  It looks like you have to do it for each and every User within the Group

Comment: @PabloBoswell - When I installed R-Services on my computer, a new Windows group call SQLRUserGroup was automatically created.  20 iindividual Windows user accounts MSSQLSERVER00 thru MSSQLSERVER20 was also created - each of which is a member of the SQLRUserGroup.  I merely granted the Windows group with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to grant this group permissions to shared/network drives?